# How can I programatically convert SVG files containing text to PDF files (specifically on CentOS 5.3 x86_64)?

Tags: pdf, image-processing, svg, batik, inkscape

I would like to programatically convert SVG files to PDF files. However, the SVG files contain text that must be searchable in the generated PDF files. Also, it has to work on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.3 or CentOS 5.3 for the x86_64 architecture. It would be nice if it were Open Source or at least not very expensive.

Here is what I've tried. All of these, except Batik, work fine on Debian Lenny.

*[Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)*
I can get it installed using autopackages from http://inkscape.modevia.com/ap, but when I use it from the command line, the text is not searchable.

*[Batik rasterizer](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/rasterizer.html)* [sic]
When it converts SVG files to PDF files, the text is no longer searchable.

*[svg2pdf](http://cairographics.org/snapshots/)*
The source for this and several of its dependencies are available to [download](http://cairographics.org/snapshots/). I have been trying to get it to compile on CentOS, but haven't had success yet. I found a [precompiled version](http://www.xgrr.de/wordpress/?s=svg2pdf) for Debian x86_64, but it doesn't work on CentOS.

*rsvg-convert*
Generated PDF isn't searchable on CentOS 5.3. Perhaps installing a newer version of cairo would help. Thanks to DaveParillo for mentioning rsvg-convert (on superuser).

**SOLUTION** (but perhaps some of the above will still be useful to the reader)
*[princeXML](http://www.princexml.com)*
It works fine on CentOS when installed from source. For some reason it doesn't work when installed from the .rpm. Thanks Erik Dahlström!

[Cross posted on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/79043/how-can-i-batch-convert-svg-files-containing-text-to-pdf-files-specifically-on-c)

Comment: can't you compile svg2pdf on a centos machine and install in your server?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've tried it a few times, but trying to get all the dependencies set up write has been pretty difficult. I'll might come back to this one again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [princexml](http://www.princexml.com/download/), it's free for non-commercial use.